# Bar Chart inside Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, chartist.js

I want to display the following chart:

[image: Chart]

Many chart libraries allow the use of stacked bar charts, for example:

- [Chartist.js](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html#stacked-bar)
- [d3.js](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208)
- [CanvasJS](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-stacked-bar-chart/)
- etc.

But how about a chart like shown above? The idea is to provide values for the green, yellow and red area and for the black bar in the center... Based on those values such a chart should be rendered.

I thought this somehow can be realized by creating a stacked bar chart and "somehow" inserting the bar inside the stacked bar... And "somehow" putting the labels there... :D

As you can see, no clue at all... :)

Comment: Create a chart-wrapper container with relative positioning then add both charts inside that container with absolute positioning.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need those containers with those positions. You can position both charts in the SVG just using D3 scales. Just paint the stacked bar chart first and the regular bar chart later. In SVG, whatever is painted later stays on top.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean a [workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/vofhdc4e/) for bullet chart like this?

```
`data:[
  {
    type: "stackedBar100",
    toolTipContent: null,
    highlightEnabled: false,
    name: "Region 1",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: [
    {y: 60, label: "Water Filter" }

    ]
  },
   {
    type: "stackedBar100",
    toolTipContent: null,
    highlightEnabled: false,
    name: "Region 2",
    showInLegend: true,
    dataPoints: [
    {y: 20, label: "Water Filter" }

    ]
  },{
    type: "bar",
    dataPoints:[{}]

  },{
    type: "bar",
    dataPoints: [
    {y: 65, label: "Water Filter" }

    ]
  },
  {
    type: "bar",
    dataPoints:[{}]
  }

  ] `
```